# JS lambda in Clojurs script

Tags: clojurescript, clojuresque

Can I have a JS lambdas in Clojurescript? I have

```
.then((entry) => console.log(entry))
```

How will it work in CLJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda is made with `fn`:

```
(.then promise (fn [entry] (.log js/console entry)))
```